# How can we set the Hidden field value before page_load fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

I have a problem in setting the hidden field value before page_load event fire.I have a parentPage where a child window will be open using window.open(...) .I am able to access the parentPage Hiddenfield value as given below

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('hdParent').value
```

I'm trying to set this value to child page hidden field before page_Load,but it's not happening.I have written a javascript method "setHiddenField();" and calling this method in

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       setHiddenField();
    });
```

But this not happening.can anyone tell how can we do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. The asp `PageLoad` event always occur before the `jQuery.ready` function.
The page load event happens when the server renders the page and `jQuery.ready()` function executes only after that. ie, when the rendered page loaded into the browser.

If you want to pass any such values to server side, I would recommend `queryStrings`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I would try in that way , but is there any chance to handle in the Page Life Cycle?

Comment: I think, No. When you are requesting the new page(window.open) the asp will render the page after going all through the page cycles. The page_load event happens at this point. Then, when the page loaded to browser you are setting hidden field value. ie after the page_load event completes.

Answer (score 0):

Write a public method which sets the value of the HiddenField in the page load of the child control, and call that method in the page load of the parent control. The page load of the parent will be called before the page load of child.

write a method in the  child control code behind , like given below

```
public void setHiddenField()
{
  // set the child page hidden field value here
}
```

and then call the above method in the page load of the parent.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        childcontrol.setHiddenField();
}
```

Hope this helps , please let me know if not.